# Joomla 3.3 AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

The following code is in my **view/tmpl/edit.php**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
            jQuery("#button").click(function(){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:'somefile.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: {action:"1"},
                    success: function(response) {alert(response);}
                });
            });        
        </script>
```

and in the same folder i have the **somefile.php** with the following code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        SomeFunction();
 }

 function SomeFunction()
 {
    ...do something
 }
```

My problem is that when I hit the button it never access the **somefile.php** although the script is executed (checked with alerts). What am I doing wrong here?

Please show me some directions on that with some relevant sample/example code.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add `,error: function() { alert('error'); }` after `success: function(response) {alert(response);}` and see if you get the error alert.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error. In fact using the firebug for debugging, the POST returns message 200 OK

Comment: How do you know that **somefile.php** is never accessed? Where did you put the alert()?

Comment: I am running it using xdebug. I have placed breakpoints at the beginning of **somefile.php** and it never stops there. The alert() was placed inside the click event right before the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're calling 'somefile.php' as your URL that will equate to the current URL you're browsing in Joomla + the file name. It will not map to the path of your file.
   *e.g. if you're on the front page of the site* i.e. `http://example.com` the AJAX request will go to
   `http://example.com/somefile.php`
   while on a page at `http://example.com/blog/mypost01` it will map to `http://example.com/blog/somefile.php`.
   Both of these will be wrong as your file is actually somewhere like:

   `http://example.com/components/com_mycomponent/view/tmpl/somefile.php`
2. First up I would use a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to monitor the full `request` and `response`, cycle this should give you a clear idea of whats going on and the entire request/redirect/response cycle.
3. Make sure you have `Error Reporting` turned all the way up to `Development` and Joomla DEBUG mode enabled, that way you may see errors rather than a `200` result being returned.
4. Some Joomla 3 `htaccess` configurations and security extensions (AdminTools) will prevent direct access to `php` files. If this is the problem, it's probably a sign that you're doing it in an unsafe/incorrect way.
5. Since you're using Joomla 3.3 read about Us[ing Joomla Ajax Interface](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface) on the [Joomla Doc's site](http://docs.joomla.org/).
6. Finally, as you appear to be building your own component, you could/should be passing the AJAX call via your component and to a method in a suitable controller rather than accessing a PHP file directly.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I had already moved to point 6. Also, how do I pass parameters to the method in the call assuming that this is a GET call? Thanks again!!!

Comment: If you're using [`JInput`](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) (as you should be in a Joomla controller) then you don't have to worry about whether a `get` or `post` is used.